# c++ primer plus Partial Specializations question

Tags: c++, class, templates

In the "Partial Specializations" section of chapter 14 of C++ Primer Plus:

> Without the partial specialization, the second declaration would use the general template, interpreting T as type char *.With the partial specialization, it uses the specialized template, interpreting T as char.
> The partial specialization feature allows for making a variety of restrictions. For example, you can use the following:
>
> // general template
> template <class T1, class T2, class T3> class Trio{...};
>
> // specialization with T3 set to T2
> template <class T1, class T2> class Trio<T1, T2, T2> {...};
>
> // specialization with T3 and T2 set to T1*
> template  class Trio<T1, T1*, T1*> {...};
>
> Given these declarations, the compiler would make the following choices:
>
> Trio<int, short, char *> t1; // use general template
> Trio<int, short> t2; // use Trio<T1, T2, T2>
> Trio<char, char *, char *> t3; // use Trio<T1, T1*, T1*>

But when I try this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        cout << "general definition" << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class Base<T1, T2, T2>
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        cout << "T1 and T2 definition" << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T1>
class Base<T1, T1, T1>
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        cout << "T1 definition" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base<int, char, double> b1;
    Base<int, char, char> b2;
    Base<int, char> b3;
    Base<int, int, int> b4;
    Base<int> b5;
    return 0;
}
```

I get errors in `Base<int, char> b3` and `Base<int> b5`:

```
wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 3)
wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
```

My question is: When we use partial specializations, if we use a type parameter to initialize another, can we omitting the repetitive part?

My compiler parameters:

```
D:\MinGw-x64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe 'c:\Users\33065\Desktop\study\C++ Primer Plus source code\*.cpp', '-o', 'c:\Users\33065\Desktop\study\C++ Primer Plus source code/main.exe', '-std=c++11', '-g', '-m64', '-Wall', '-static-libgcc', '-fexec-charset=GBK', '-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial specialization will expect as many template arguments as the base template mandates ("base" meaning the unspecialized declaration of your class template, NOT the type named `Base`). A solution to your problem would be to define the base template as:

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename T2 = T1, typename T3 = T2>
class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        cout << "general defination" << endl;
    }
};
```

Since specializations can't have defaulted template arguments, this makes the base template trickle down non-defined parameters to the rest of the typelist. Hence you can write things like:

```cpp
Base<T1> b1; // this will be Base<T1, T1, T1>
```

and have each undefined type equate to the previous type.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bad5c4415eceb32)

Comment: Thank you for your time! But does that mean the part in C++ Primer Plus where I quote is wrong? Just want to be sure.

Comment: @user10674784 I don't see anything wrong in the quotation apart from the part that says `Trio<int, short> t2; // use Trio<T1, T2, T2>`. Are you sure it doesn't say `Trio<int, short, short>`? The rest of the examples use 3 template parameters, as expected by the non-specialized defnition (and as expected by the compiler)

Comment: @user10674784 Yes C++ Primer Plus is absolutely wrong here.